# Is cornstarch and AP flour really a good substiture for cake flour?

Tags: substitutions, flour, cornstarch

I was just putting away my cornstarch when I saw this on the label: To make cake flour: For 1 cup cake flour combine 3/4 cup plus 2 Tbsp. all-purpose flour with 2 Tbsp. Argo Corn Starch.

Of course I see this two days after paying a ridiculous amount of money for Softasilk.

I usually use AP flour for simple cakes, but I'm making some really fussy desserts for the holidays. Some of those recipes call for cake flour and I've always gone ahead and bought cake flour for that kind of thing. Would I really get as good a result with that substitution?

Comment: I will say that it is a good substitution, because technically, there is no difference - it is like asking if mixing salt and garlic powder is a good substitute for garlic salt. But as I have never actually baked with the "real" products, always with the substitutions (meaning it in both directions here - ap + starch as well as ap + gluten), I will not make this an answer, because sometimes the real world doesn't behave according to theory :)

Comment: @rumtscho There is no cornstarch or anything else but flour and "enrichments" listed in the ingredients of my cake flour (Softasilk).

Comment: I think it would be useful to split this question into two.

Comment: Cake flour is milled from soft summer wheat, finely ground, and bleached.  It is not a blend of products.

Comment: I have never done this substitution.  In practice, unless you are an extreme stickler, almost any cake you make at home will come out quite well with all all-purpose, especially if you are using one of the softer brands (that is, *not* King Arthur).

Comment: Of course starch isn't listed. A wheat berry contains gluten and starch and bran. The bran is removed for non-whole flours. The pastry flour is made from layers and/or wheat cultivars with high starch to gluten ratio. The "mixing" of gluten and starch occurs during wheat growth. It is still a mixture of gluten and starch.

Comment: Of course I know that cake flour is lower in protein and higher in starch. We just see the question differently because in US grocery stores Americans choose between AP flour, cake flour and bread flour. I've never added starch or gluten to AP flour for cakes or breads, I had never before even heard of such a thing. I just use the flour that's listed in the recipe. I think that's pretty typical of amateur bakers in the US. Either that, or we just use AP for everything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Substitute for Pastry Flour from Limited Traditional and Alternative Flours](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/29444/substitute-for-pastry-flour-from-limited-traditional-and-alternative-flours)

Comment: @Mien It's not really a dupe, one of the answers of that question applies here, but the questions are very different. I looked for dupes before I asked this question and I saw the question to which you refer, but I didn't even read the answers because the question didn't seem to be at all similar to this question.

Comment: @Mien Actually the last line of the other question IS a dupe, I just now saw it. When I looked before, I stopped reading and dismissed it as a possible dupe because it initially seems to be about something else entirely.

Comment: @Jolenealaska yes indeed, although the other question is broader while yours is to the point. I'm not 100% sure it is a dupe, but that is why we have a community :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all revolves around gluten and gluten chains.

Cake flour is low protein, and bread flour is high protein, and everything else lies somewhere between. Individual brands have different levels of protein depending on their formulation. That protein, when combined with water, is what makes your stretchy gluten chains, and *those* are the difference between soft crumbly cake and a french baguette that could serve as a weapon in a pinch.

As with many chemical reactions in cooking, however, you can interfere with the "natural" reactions by means of some clever chemistry. Cornstarch works very simply...Corn just doesn't have any gluten, so you're just "watering down" the gluten content of your flour.

Acid retards gluten formation. Water is critical for gluten formation, unless you use a whole lot of it, in which case it weakens it (a wetter dough will make for a less gluteny final product). Mixing makes more gluten (helps the little proteins make friends with each other), so mix MORE for more gluten, and less for less.

But fat is your friend. Fat waterproofs your flour, and keeps gluten from forming.

Long story short, pick a method you're comfortable with, and stick to it. If you're used to using AP flour, you're going to have some headscratching moments when the cake flour doesn't behave the way you expect it to. On the other hand, cake flour will be more forgiving if you overmix.

Comment: So fat is not your friend when you're making bread? Do you need to knead an enriched dough more than a standard one? Or is the amount of fat small enough to not prevent gluten formation? Even in brioche?

Comment: @Mien: You'll notice a difference in proportions, in the recipes. Cake tends to have a much higher proportion of fat to flour than bread does. And all that kneading is for gluten formation: bread is mixed *far* more than cakes or quickbreads. If your bread tends to be crumbly and lacking in structural integrity, might want to look into a higher protein flour...On the other hand, if you can't chew it, might want to go the other way ;)

Comment: I generally use whatever flour (cake, AP or bread) the recipe calls for. I might use AP instead of one of the others if it's just a simple throw together thing. I make a fussy angel food cake that's kind of a special to me. Even the granulated sugar gets almost powdered in the food processor. Could AP plus cornstarch really replace cake flour in something like that, or is more of an emergency substitution kind of thing?

Comment: @Jolenealaska: Angel Food has so much protein in it (egg whites are pure protein), I'd think the type of flour would be redundant ;)...The King Arthur AP flour version (http://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/traditional-angel-food-cake-recipe) is virtually identical to the traditional cake flour version (and KA flour is very high in protein). I don't think I'd add cornstarch for AP Angel Food: all those eggs, and the cream of tartar should cover the difference in protein between normal AP and cake flour.

Comment: @Satanicpuppy You certainly have a point, although I'm not totally convinced. A brioche can have about butter to flour in a 1:2 proportion, while I have baked cakes which had almost no fat.