# Substitute for pastry flour

Tags: dough, pastry

[The recipe](http://video.pbs.org/video/1174110297/) calls for pastry flour which I can't find here. I would like a substitution which results exactly the same dough as they show in the video.

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/29444/67

Comment: You can make perfectly good puff pastry with plain/all-purpose flour - pastry flour is just a 'bonus'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what you have available, it's difficult to give a recommendation.  The common substitutions are:

- a blend of all purpose and cake flours (either 50:50, or 5:3 favoring the cake flour)
- a blend of all purpose flour and cornstarch.  (2TB starch to a scant 1 cup of flour)

The first one will give you closer to what you're looking for.  The second one might not be quite as tender.

Answer (score 2):

Pastry flour is typically milled finer, and has a lower protein content. Low protein means less gluten, which will give a flakier result. If packaging in your area tells protein content then compare them and pick the one with the least protein. As for milling that probably won't make that much difference for what you are making.